# How to convert time into days

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I have got this data in a table. Using SQL server. I need to create a report in which I need to add this duration and convert into days, datatype of duration column is timestamp. When I use Sum on this i get this error **Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.**

What is the best way of converting this to number of days?

```html
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>TicketNumber</th>
        <th>duration</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>521163</td>
        <td>44:08:11</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>906868</td>
        <td>404:55:27</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>140013</td>
        <td>412:08:03</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: [`RowVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), aka `timestamp`, doesn't store a date, time or any combination of thereof. An aggregate of `RowVersion` doesn't make sense. [`Time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), for what it is worth, is limited to values <24 hours. Are you trying to `sum` various `time` values to get a result in Yet Another Data Type that will represent some number of days?

Comment: Yes, like i have got values like, 44:08:11
45:38:35
48:50:31
75:15:59
76:23:49
78:20:27
80:16:08
81:17:28, need to add these values and convert total number of hours into days

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. `44:08:11 45:38:35 48:50:31 75:15:59 76:23:49 78:20:27 80:16:08 81:17:28` is not a `rowversion` value or a valid IPv6 address. Without the actual datatype or the expected result we'll have to do some guessing to help you. That's a waste of your time as well as ours. Perhaps the correct result for the cryptic strings in your question is `N'XXXVI'`. Or do you need (proper) fractions of a day?

Comment: Not clear from your description if you have a table  or HTML code. You speak about table but present HTML code. If you have a table then we need to get a table = query to create the table and insert the sample data. If you have HTML code which you need to parse then you DO NOT HAVE A TABLE but a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear from your description if you have a TABLE or HTML code! You speak about table but present HTML code.

If you have a table then we need to get a table, which means queries to create the table and insert the sample data. If you have HTML code, which you need to parse then you DO NOT HAVE A TABLE but a text.

Assuming that you have HTML code as presented in the question then you have an XML code which mean that you can use the function OPENXML to parse the data from the HTML code as presented here:

```
DECLARE @HTML as XML
SELECT @HTML = '
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>TicketNumber</th>
        <th>duration</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>521163</td>
        <td>44:08:11</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>906868</td>
        <td>404:55:27</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>140013</td>
        <td>412:08:03</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
'
SELECT @HTML

------------------ First we will learn how to parse the HTML data to get table structure
-- Note! This base on exact format of the HTML code!
-- Any change in the format will fail this solution
DECLARE @handle INT
DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT  
EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @HTML  

SELECT id, MyTime
FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/table/tbody/tr', 1)  
    WITH (
        id NVARCHAR(MAX) '(td)[1]',
        MyTime NVARCHAR(MAX) '(td)[2]'
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Using this approach, we can now use the data in the result SET from the above query and calculate the SUM of the times, as presented here (this should be your solution):

```
DECLARE @HTML as XML
SELECT @HTML = '
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>TicketNumber</th>
        <th>duration</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>521163</td>
        <td>44:08:11</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>906868</td>
        <td>404:55:27</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>140013</td>
        <td>412:08:03</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
'
DECLARE @handle INT
DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT  
EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @HTML  

---------------- Now we can use the above way of parsiong the HTML in order to calculate the SUM of the times
EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @HTML  

;With MyCTE as (
SELECT id, MyTime
    FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/table/tbody/tr', 1)  
        WITH (
            id NVARCHAR(MAX) '(td)[1]',
            MyTime NVARCHAR(MAX) '(td)[2]'
        )
),
-- Convert Seconds, minutes, hours to INT and sum
MyCTE1 as(
    SELECT 
        MySec  = SUM(CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyTime,':','.'),1))),
        MyMin  = SUM(CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyTime,':','.'),2))),
        MyHour = SUM(CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyTime,':','.'),3)))
    from MyCTE
),
-- Move from seconds to minutes and from minutes to hours if the value above 60
MyCTE2 as(
    SELECT 
        MySec  = (MySec%60),
        MyMin  = (MyMin + (MySec/60)) % 60, 
        MyHour = MyHour + ((MyMin + (MySec/60)) / 60)
    from MyCTE1
)
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyHour) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MyMin),2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MySec),2) 
FROM MyCTE2

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

### Using existing table

If you already have a table (not HTML code) and all you need to find the number of days, hours, minutes, seconds then you simply need to use the end part of the above query. We do not need to parse the HTML code so we can jump to the CTE named MyCTE01.

For example, using the op DDL+DML which was provided in the comment:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OpenTickets] ( [TicketNumber] [varchar](50) NULL ,[Duration] [varchar](20) NULL )
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OpenTickets] VALUES 
    ( 521163 ,'44:08:11' ) ,( 746008 ,'45:38:35' ) ,( 120025 ,'48:50:31' ) ,( 780125 ,'75:15:59' ) ,( 903960 ,'76:23:49' ) ,
    ( 937883 ,'178:20:27' ) ,( 524404 ,'80:16:08' ) ,( 374972 ,'81:17:28' )
GO

SELECT * FROM [OpenTickets]
GO

;With MyCTE1 as(
    SELECT 
        MySec  = SUM(CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE([Duration],':','.'),1))),
        MyMin  = SUM(CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE([Duration],':','.'),2))),
        MyHour = SUM(CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE([Duration],':','.'),3)))
    from [OpenTickets]
),
-- Move from seconds to minutes and from minutes to hours if the value above 60
MyCTE2 as(
    SELECT 
        MySec  = (MySec%60),
        MyMin  = (MyMin + (MySec/60)) % 60, 
        MyHour = MyHour + ((MyMin + (MySec/60)) / 60)
    from MyCTE1
)
SELECT 
    MyDays = MyHour/24,
    Total = 'Days: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyHour/24) + ' and ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyHour % 24) + ':' + 
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MyMin),2) + ':' + 
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MySec),2),
    TotalTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MyHour) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MyMin),2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MySec),2) 
FROM MyCTE2
GO
```

Comment: Hi Ronen, Thank you so much for your reply. I have got a table SQL database, two columns, ticket number and duration. Duration is total time to resolve the issue. It is in HH:MM:SS format, but some values are  146:20:49, now need to create one report and convert this duration column into days. How can I do this. e.g. Ticket number 12345 took  time 146:20:49, how can i convert this to no. of days?

Comment: @user3061338 , Please provide: (1) queries to create the table and insert some sample data. (2) What is your server version? (3) according to the sample data, what is your expected result which you want to get from the query.

Comment: Regarding the presentation of days, you can use the same approach I used in the code above to find the minutes and hours after the SUM. The number of days is the number of hours divided into 24, and the hours that stays are the number of hours modulo 24. If you provide the missing information I asked you to, then we will be able to provide a specific sample

Comment: as requested CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OpenTickets] (
 [TicketNumber] [varchar](50) NULL
 ,[Duration] [varchar](20) NULL
 )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OpenTickets]
VALUES (
 521163
 ,'44:08:11'
 )
 ,(
 746008
 ,'45:38:35'
 )
 ,(
 120025
 ,'48:50:31'
 )
 ,(
 780125
 ,'75:15:59'
 )
 ,(
 903960
 ,'76:23:49'
 )
 ,(
 937883
 ,'178:20:27'
 )
 ,(
 524404
 ,'80:16:08'
 )
 ,(
 374972
 ,'81:17:28'
 )

Comment: need duration in days

Comment: Hello @user3061338, I added to the answer above a solution for this case under the title "Using existing table".